# Ubuntu 17.10 partitions in dock

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, partitioning, ubuntu-dock, dash-shell

After installing ubuntu17.10 I was depressed by the fact that I can't add my partitions to the dock in order to easily mount and open them, I locked around on google, ubuntu forums and I got nothing, so I appreciate if any one could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can only add applications (i.e. packages which have a `.desktop` file either in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`) to the dock not folders or shortcuts. This is a feature-limitation which is likely to be fixed in the next versions of Dash To Dock (and the Ubuntu dock by extension).

If you want to have your mounted-partitions visible at all times then the [Removable Drive Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/) extension can help with that. This extension makes any mounted partition permanently visible in the right corner of the top-panel.

If you'd like this feature in the dock then you can use [Dash To Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) to transform the top-panel into a dock.